# Traverse tetrahedra and vertices in subdomains generated by CGAL

Tags: c++, computational-geometry, triangulation, cgal

CGAL provides an example in Chapter 3D Mesh Generation that produces a 3D mesh from an 3D segmented image, see code at http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2mesh_3D_image_8cpp-example.html

The resultant domain consists of several **subdomains**, each of which has been **delaunay triangulated** into tetrahedra, i.e. each subdomain actually corresponds to a tetrahedral mesh. My questions are:

1. How to specify a subdomain for traversing?
2. Given a specified subdomain, how to traverse the tetrahedra and vertices because I want to pass the result into my own data structure?

Comment: Please explain what sort of data you want to pass to your own data structure.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a look at the file `CGAL/IO/Complex_3_in_triangulation_3_to_vtk.h` which converts a C3T3 into a `vtkUnstructuredGrid`. You can modify the code to fill your own data structure.

Comment: got it, but how to traverse every subdomain?

Comment: use [`c3t3.subdomain_index(c);`](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/classMeshComplex__3InTriangulation__3.html#abc072e73be6bf1d3143f741583b2306a)